# ガンアゲ translation/meaning

Tags: translation, slang

Can someone tell me the meaning of ガンアゲ? It's giving me a hard time

The sentence is 気分になると一気にガンアゲになっし

Answer (score 6):

ガンアゲ is a no-adjective that roughly means "(extremely) hyped up". It is considered as a ギャル語/JK語 word.

Etymologically, there is a phrase テンションが上がる, which is a little slangy phrase meaning "to be excited" or "to be hyped up". The antonym is テンションが下がる ("to be turned off"). Someone started to contract it and say テンアゲ/テンサゲ. Then someone even shortened it and coined アゲ/サゲ. ガンアゲ is a stronger version of アゲ. This ガン is a slangy intensifier similar to 超. It's also found in [ガン見](http://zokugo-dict.com/06ka/ganmi.htm) and [ガン無視](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%AC%E3%83%B3%E7%84%A1%E8%A6%96).